# Who exactly is the "she" that Harry is referring to?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Harry Potter asks Vernon to sign some form:

> Harry Potter: Nothing. School stuff.
>
> Vernon: Later perhaps, if you behave.
>
> Harry Potter: I will if **she** does.

Who exactly is "she" Harry referring to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clearly referring to **Aunt Marge**, who is a terrible person that treated Harry poorly in the past.